# how to sort a dictionary and get only first and last element

Tags: python

I have written a program in which I am counting he frequency of a letter occurred in a string.

```
Input: AAAABBBBBCCDEEEEEEEEEEFFF
```

I want my output to be only those letter which occurred most and least number of times, and with the number of times they occurred.

```
import sys
seq=sys.argv[1]
count = {}
for i in seq:
  if count.has_key(i):
    count[i] += 1
  else:
    count[i] = 1

for i in sorted(count, key=count.get, reverse=True):
  print i, count[i]
```

output:

```
 Actual Output:
 E:10, B:5, A:4, F:3, C:2, D:1

Expected Output:
E: 10 , D: 1
```

Comment: As well as `collections.Counter`, it's worth learning about `collections.defaultdict` to avoid having to write if statements like the one you wrote in more general statements. Also `dict.setdefault`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much there. There's just no reason for you to be iterating over the whole sorted dictionary.

```
sorted_count = sorted(count, key=count.get, reverse=True)
print sorted_count[0]
print sorted_count[-1]
```

Alternatively:

```
print min(count, key=count.get)
print max(count, key=count.get)
```

Comment: It's only returning the alphabet , I mean E, D not their values like E:10 , D:1

Comment: That's trivial to fix. You have a dictionary, you can access values by key. So `count[sorted_count[0]]` will give you the count. You can also use `sorted(count.items(), key=lambda item: item[0], reverse=True)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count the letters:

```
>>> import operator, collections
>>> counter = collections.Counter('AAAABBBBBCCDEEEEEEEEEEFFF')
Counter({'E': 10, 'B': 5, 'A': 4, 'F': 3, 'C': 2, 'D': 1})

>>> sorted_counter = sorted(counter, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[('E', 10), ('B', 5), ('A', 4), ('F', 3), ('C', 2), ('D', 1)]   

>>> print sorted_counter[-1]
('D', 1)

>>> print sorted_counter[0]
('E', 10)
```

Comment: No need to sort: `min` and `max` have `key` parameters as well.

Comment: without using collections and operators.